# pytorch conv2d with weights

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, convolution

I have these 2 variables:

```
result- tensor 1 X 251 X 20
kernel - tensor 1 X 10 X 10
```

when I run the command:

```
from torch.nn import functional as F
result = F.conv2d(result, kernel)
```

I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: expected stride to be a single integer value or a list of 1 values to match the convolution dimensions, but got stride=[1, 1]
```

I am not giving any stride, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Conv2d means 4D data (B\*C\*H\*W) and 4D kernel weights. Yours seem to be wrong.

Comment: I fixed the data size to be 1 X 1 X 251 X 20, but I still get the stride error.
It looks like it is related to the weights and not the data

Comment: BOTH the data and weight need to have 4 dimensions. For the weight it's something like (input channel, output channel, h, w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
image = torch.rand(16, 3, 32, 32)
filter = torch.rand(1, 3, 5, 5)
out_feat_F = F.conv2d(image, filter,stride=1, padding=0)
print(out_feat_F.shape)
```

Out:

```
torch.Size([16, 1, 28, 28])
```

Which is equivalent with:

```
import torch
import torch.nn
image = torch.rand(16, 3, 32, 32)
conv_filter = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=1, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=0)
output_feature = conv_filter(image)
print(output_feature.shape)
```

Out:

```
torch.Size([16, 1, 28, 28])
```

Padding is by default 0, stride is by default 1.
The filter last two dimensions in the first example correspond to the
kernel size in the second example.

`kernel_size=5` is the same as `kernel_size=(5,5)`.